# simplify the expression ${\sqrt{x - 2\sqrt{x -1}} +\sqrt{x + 2\sqrt{x -1}}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

> Simplify the expression ${\sqrt{x - 2\sqrt{x -1}} +\sqrt{x + 2\sqrt{x -1}}}$

The problem is from a **not** so well renowned book for calculus in India - Concepts of Functions & Calculus - Vikas Rahi, ISBN 9780070080805. The answer for this question is given as
$$\lvert \sqrt{x-1} -1  \rvert + \lvert \sqrt{x-1}+1 \rvert$$
My efforts weren't great at all, I tried rationalizing them but the denominator becomes very similar to the question, which is totally not helpful for simplification.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: can you show me your efforts ???

Answer (score 5):

Write $t =\sqrt{x-1}$ then your expression is $$\sqrt{t^2+1+2t} +\sqrt{t^2+1-2t} =|t+1|+|t-1| $$

Notice that $t\geq 0$. So if $t\geq 1$ we get $2t$ and if $t<1$ we get $2$.

Comment: very very nice solution. you really deserve +1

Comment: I am really a beginner in this, can you please help me in understanding how you solved this? I would be grateful

Comment: When ever you something repeating it then try to mark it with some ne variable and then expres old variable with new one.

Answer (score 3):

First, note that
\begin{align}
(1 \pm \sqrt{x-1})^2
&= 1 \pm 2 \sqrt{x-1} + \sqrt{x-1}^2 \\
&= 1 \pm 2 \sqrt{x-1} + x-1 & x \geq 1 \\
&= x \pm 2 \sqrt{x-1}
\end{align}

Thus, since $\sqrt{u^2} = |u|$,
\begin{align}
f(x)
&= \sqrt{x-2\sqrt{x-1}}+\sqrt{x+2\sqrt{x-1}} \\
&= \sqrt{(1-\sqrt{x-1})^2}+\sqrt{(1+\sqrt{x-1})^2} & x \geq 1 \\
&= |1-\sqrt{x-1}|+|1+\sqrt{x-1}| \\
&= \begin{cases}
(1-\sqrt{x-1})+(1+\sqrt{x-1}) & 1 \leq x < 2 \\
-(1-\sqrt{x-1})+(1+\sqrt{x-1}) & 2 \leq x
\end{cases} \\
&= \begin{cases}
2 & 1 \leq x < 2 \\
2 \sqrt{x-1} & 2 \leq x
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Just write

\begin{eqnarray*} \sqrt{x - 2\sqrt{x -1}} +\sqrt{x + 2\sqrt{x -1}}
& = & \sqrt{x -1 - 2\sqrt{x -1} +1} +\sqrt{x -1 + 2\sqrt{x -1} +1} \\
& = & \sqrt{(\sqrt{x-1}-1)^2} + \sqrt{(\sqrt{x-1}+1)^2} \\
& = & \begin{cases} 2 & 1 \leq x\leq 2 \\ 2\sqrt{x-1} & x>2 \end{cases} 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I think this is the correct solution, perfectly matches textbook's answer plus you stated the expression's value w.r.t. domain's of x

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}{\sqrt{x - 2\sqrt{x -1}} +\sqrt{x + 2\sqrt{x -1}}}&=T(x)>0&\end{align}$$

$$T^2(x)=2x+2 \sqrt{x^2-4x+4}$$

$$T^2(x)=2x+2|x-2|$$

$$\begin{align}\color {gold}{\boxed {\color{black}{T(x)=\sqrt{2x+2|x-2|}}}}\end{align}$$

---

- If $x≥2$, then $\begin{align}T(x)&=\sqrt{2x+2x-4}\\
  &=2\sqrt{x-1}\end{align}$
- If $x<2$, then $\begin{align}T(x)=\sqrt{2x+4-2x}=2.\end{align}$

Comment: @DonAntonio You are right. ! Thank you very much for report it.

Answer (score 1):

"Simplify" can easily depend on the beholder's eyes, but one idea (and hint) is:

$$\sqrt{a-b}+\sqrt{a+b}=\frac{2b}{\sqrt{a+b}-\sqrt{a-b}}$$

I  don't really think we get a huge simplifaction here but...perhaps something like this is what is meant in that book.

Comment: True ! Good catch, I shall delete, and I'll upvote your answer as it looks the best one here. Thanks.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up for my solution, it clearly doesn't lead me to any conclusion.